# ASP.NET Unit Testing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I'm searching for a good ASP.NET Unit Testing tool. Googling gives me some tools, but I would like to get started with a good tool.

Any experience with these tools?

Is there a way to do ASP.NET Unit Tests with the build-in Unit Testing in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [WATIN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/), It's very very powerful I think.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use Selenium RC.

Answer (score 0):

[nUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php) would be my suggestion over the built in unit testing that Visual Studio has.